# Entity Framework Transaction Queueing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

If this exists, how does Entity Framework manage a series of generated Transactions?

For example I have a series of data operations and I perform a process like this as discrete Transactions:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; ++i) {
    using (DbContextTransaction trx = dbCtx.Database.BeginTransaction()) {
        MakeSomeAdditionsOrChanges(list[i]);
        SaveChanges();
        trx.Commit();
    }
}
```

Is there any Internal queueing?

Is this the best or is there a better approach to dealing with a series of data tasks?

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. Try to reduce it to a problem/challenge you're currently facing in *actual* code.

Comment: A core tenet of database systems is that when the committing of a transaction is reported back to the caller, the database has changed (durability). "Queueing" transactions would break that model. You can, of course, have a series of modifications inside one transaction -- those are "queued" in the sense that they all happen when the transaction commits, or they are all rolled back if the transaction is aborted.

Comment: I think you need to consider your business and technical intentions and split out the work as required. Your design is more about transaction isolation level. If each piece of work is independent then you can proceed with multiple SaveChanges(). If all changes should fail on an issue with any work, use just one SaveChanges()